# Collect attributes from a XML file by XMLReader

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file as below.

```
<BOOK bnumber="1" bname="Book">
    <CHAPTER cnumber="1">
       <Sentence vnumber="1">This is the sentence 1.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="2">This is the sentence 2.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="3">This is the sentence 3.</Sentence>
   </CHAPTER>
   <CHAPTER cnumber="2">
       <Sentence vnumber="1">Hello World 1.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="2">Hello World 2.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="3">Hello World 3.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="4">Hello World 4.</Sentence>
  </CHAPTER>
  <CHAPTER cnumber="3">
       <Sentence vnumber="1">Good morning 1.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="2">Good morning 2.</Sentence>
       <Sentence vnumber="3">Good morning 3.</Sentence>
  </CHAPTER>
</BOOK>
```

What I want is to collect the attributes of "CHAPTER".
The goal is to get

```
Chapter={"Chapter 1";"Chapter 2","Chapter 3"};
```

Current I use tradition method,

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:\books.xml"); //load the xml file into our document
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes(@"//BOOK/CHAPTER[@cnumber='" + chap
string sentences = "";
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes) {
   sentences += node.InnerText + "; ";
}
```

but I want to use XMLReader because the XML file is big, I don't want to load it in memory.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code againt the `XMLReader` yet?

Comment: Not yet, I am not strong on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basicly you can do like this:

```
        var chapters = new List<string>();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("CHAPTER");
            reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            string chapterNumber = reader.Value;
            chapters.Add("Chapter " + chapterNumber);
        }
```

where the xmlString is your xml.

This will find the first chapter and get the attribute from it and add it to a list of chapters.

Comment: the xmlString is MY xml, but is it big. Say 20MB. Can we do in this way?

Comment: `XmlReader.Create` also has an overload that can take any `Stream` object.  That is what you will want to do.  Create a stream which will read from the XML source, then pass that stream to the `Create` method instead of a new `StringReader` (e.g. `XmlReader.Create(myStream)`).

Comment: I meant that does xmlString refer to the entire xml file here?